# Flutter TextFormField( decoration: ..., suffix: IconButton( onPressed: , )); icon button onPress error

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-android

I want to give my input type as password so I want it as censored. I want to use "obscureText: true," so it works but when I want to declare it a function and add a button that will show the password when you click and hide when you click it again. I am trying to add suffix property and IconButton(); but it is not working.

```
bool hide() {
  return true;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Form(
    key: loginClass,
    ...
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 8),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: password,
            obscureText: hide(),
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Password",
              hintText: "Enter your password",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              icon: Icon(Icons.lock),

              // Suffix line.

              suffix: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.visibility_rounded),
                onPressed: !hide, // Error line.
              ),

            ),
            validator: (String? value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your password';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
        ),
       ...
}
```

Error:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...

lib/login.dart:107:31: Error: Not a constant expression.
                  onPressed: !hide,
                              ^^^^

lib/login.dart:107:31: Error: A value of type 'bool Function()' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.
                  onPressed: !hide,
                              ^

lib/login.dart:107:30: Error: The argument type 'bool' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.
                  onPressed: !hide,
                             ^

Restarted application in 218ms.
```

I want to add a icon button. Once you click it, the password will be shown but if you click again will be censored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare a boolean variable and change its value depending on the visibility button. Also, if you do not use BLOC or GETX, you must use a stateful widget to obtain the screens' updates. Also, Do not use const if you assign an onPressed function with a function or setState.
I have done an example code for you... you can try it directly on the browser through this link: https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zn206ban306?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart

Comment: This is not works too...

Comment: Abd El Rahman thank you! Your code work on me. The problem on 'decoration' property on my code. It must not be declared as const.

Comment: You're welcome, Beresys! Yes, as I told you in the answer, you do not have to use const if you use setState on the onPressed Function and so on! Wish you a happy day!

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Pass(),
  ));
}

class Pass extends StatefulWidget {
  const Pass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Pass> createState() => _PassState();
}

class _PassState extends State<Pass> {
  bool hidePassword = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextFormField(
          obscureText: hidePassword,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Password',
            hintText: 'Enter Password',
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                hidePassword ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  hidePassword = !hidePassword;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

then you can try this

Comment: This usage giving error. The error in pic. https://i.postimg.cc/fWdFnCD8/resim-2022-10-31-135414295.png

Answer (score 0):

```
suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                          _isObscure
                              ? Icons.visibility_outlined
                              : Icons.visibility_off_outlined,
                          color: HexColor(CustomAppTheme.borderColor),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
```

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/8z0yLjL0/resim-2022-10-31-142521812.png It is not working...

Comment: @Beresyus please copy the code properly. this is a tested code.

Answer (score -1):

`onPressed` could be either `null` or a `function`, you can't assign `!hide` to it. Create a new state variable to maintain the state of visibility in the StatefulWidget.

```dart
suffix: IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.visibility_rounded),
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      hideState = !hideState;
    });   
  },
),
```

Comment: The "hide" is a function in the program, am I supposed to make it variable?

Comment: This usage giving error. For the error; https://i.postimg.cc/fWdFnCD8/resim-2022-10-31-135414295.png

Comment: create a StatefulWidget.

Comment: I already extend it statefulwidget.